# Receive a notification key from ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have the following command where I get my notification in ios, I want to get my key more I'm not getting it, what I tried was

```
   public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        Messaging.SharedInstance.AppDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);

        NSString[] keys = { new NSString("Event_type") };
        NSObject[] values = { new NSString("Recieve_Notification") };
        var parameters = NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>.FromObjectsAndKeys(keys, values, keys.Length);

        Firebase.Analytics.Analytics.LogEvent("CustomEvent", parameters);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(userInfo);

        // var aps_d = userInfo["aps"] as NSDictionary;
        //var alert_d = aps_d["alert"] as NSDictionary;
        //var body = alert_d["keys"] as NSString;
    }
```

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine 
receive this

```
[0:] {
aps =     {
    alert =         {
        body = "teste";
        title = "teste";
    };
};
"gcm.message_id" = "0:1505400569099941%712ac0f8712a1234";
"gcm.n.e" = 1;
"google.c.a.c_id" = 5974019197827881234;
"google.c.a.c_l" = "teste";
"google.c.a.e" = 1;
"google.c.a.ts" = 1505400123;
"google.c.a.udt" = 0;
keys = 152113;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`keys` is a top level and last entry in the dictionary, so you can directly access it via `userInfo["keys"]`, i.e:

```
var keys = userInfo["keys"] as NSString;
```